# Username argument is invalid in SharePointOnlineCredentials - CSOM

Tags: csom, credentials, exception

I wrote a simple code in CSOM to get web title. Hope code is fine. When I execute my application I got an exception from my third line
`(clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("Domain\\Username", SecurePassword);)`

> Username argument is invalid

Any idea to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://siteURL"))
{
    SecureString SecurePassword = GetSecureString("password");
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("Domain\\Username", SecurePassword);
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.Load(web,
    webSite => webSite.Title);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
}
```

Comment: your tag says SharePoint-enterprise, while your code has `SharePointOnlineCredential`. What actual version of SharePoint you are using? SPO or SP?

Comment: I use CSOM. Tag has been edited

Comment: I guess you are working with SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is very simple and clear.

While passing credentials do not use `Domain` name along with username. You just need to use `Username`.

So your code will be like:

```
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("Username", SecurePassword);
```

If it is SharePoint On-Prem then `SharePointOnlineCredential` is not required.

In such case you should use:

```
NetworkCredential _myCredentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain"); // While domain will be your site url
//OR
NetworkCredential _myCredentials = new NetworkCredential(@"domain\user", "password");
```

and then pass credential as

```
clientContext.Credentials = _myCredentials;
```

Comment: Great @Aakash. It works

Comment: Glad!! It worked....